OpenSSL RAND_bytes causing return value 3221225477 (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
I had some errors in my code and I was able to pinpoint the issue to the RAND_bytes function
Basically no matter how I use this function I kept ending up with return value 3221225477 after compiling, which is the STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Minimal reproducible example:
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned char buf[16] = {0};
    cout << "Line1" << endl;
    int re = RAND_bytes(buf, sizeof(buf)); //the rest won't be executed, indicated by the cout
    cout << "Line2" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++)
        cout << (int)buf[i] << " ";
    cout << "Line3" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

Additional information:

Placing the entire code in (try...catch) does not result in any error
Errors: 0, Warnings: 0, even in debugger mode
Also tried some other implementations of RAND_bytes (Code1, text)

It's worth noting to mention that

I can't use another compiler (I'm a student and my teacher wouldn't allow it)
I'm using Dev-C++, version 5.11, OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023), and of all the tutorials I found are either in linux/mac, or in windows but in CodeBlocks/VS, it's very likely that something went wrong with my settings (using the "keyword" searching in google does not yield any useful result, including "RAND_bytes" "3221225477")

Here are my settings on my compiler:
Project Options -> Linker (Can't see the full pic, its in the form ../../../../OpenSSL/3.3.0/lib/libcrypto.lib, my code is inside a folder in my desktop, added via the built-in search feature so this directory should be correct
Compiler Options -> Binaries
Compiler Options -> Libaries
Compiler Options -> C++ includes
I can't response right now until 8 hours, sorry for inconvenience
Edit1: Finally was able to edit this question, fixed the typo in the strings
The output is:
Line1
--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.541 seconds with return value 3221225477

Edit2: It seems like some parts of the text was removed, heres the missing parts:
The given code generates 16 random bytes then outputs it,
Debugging shows SIGSEGV, which agrees with the compiler's return value 3221225477, but these codes are from the past to which I have not found any issue regarding the recent version causing this issue
Also tried the code without using namespace std, same error

Note: cout << "Line1 << endl; and cout << "Line3 << endl; are both missing a ".

I accidentally deleted that whilst editing the format in stack overflow, there should be a " there

Please show a compilable [mre]

Please show the actual output when you run this code.

The error suggests that somehow the RAND_bytes function is trying to access an invalid address. How or why this may happen is not easy to discover. Have you tried running this code in the debugger?

Are you sure that you're loading the same openssl version as the one you're lining against?

Yes, as I've mentioned debugger shows SIGSEGV, and the error occurred at the line containing RAND_bytes. I'm not sure how to "run in debugger", pressing F8 (debug) shows a CPU window along with some assembly, what should I paste in order to provide useful information?

A stack trace showing the involved dlls might help

How do I show the stack trace? The compiled version does not have any error, and the debugger probably contains stack trace (but I don't see it: I've dealt with java before and it does not really have that form of a stack trace) but CTRL + F didn't have any result relating to .dll
